# How to Deploy non-Migratable Contract in Zeppelin OS?

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin, upgrading, openzeppelin-sdk

I am using Zeppelin OS to create a migratable contract `MyContract`, which will be imported into another contract `Foo`. `Foo` calls the `baz()` function of `MyContract`, so when `MyContract` is upgraded, `Foo` should be calling the upgraded code automatically.

**MyContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
import 'zos-lib/contracts/migrations/Migratable.sol';

contract MyContract is Migratable {
    uint256 public x;

    function initialize(uint256 _x) isInitializer("MyContract", "0") public {
        x = _x;
    }

    function baz() public returns (uint256) {
        decrement();
        return x;
    }

    function increment() public {
        x += 1;
    }

    function decrement() public {
        x -= 1;
    }
}
```

**Foo.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import './MyContract.sol';

contract Foo {
    uint256 public x;
    MyContract myContract;
    address myContractAddress;

    constructor(address _myContractAddress) public {
        myContractAddress = _myContractAddress;
    }

    function baz() public {
        myContract = MyContract(myContractAddress);
        x = myContract.baz();
    }
}
```

I am deploying MyContract and its proxy by running

```
zos add MyContract
zos push --network local
zos create MyContract --init initialize --args 42 --network local
```

How can I deploy `Foo.sol`?